# (Spring-Batch) Autowired is not working well in StepScopeTestExecutionListener

Tags: scope, spring-batch

I'm trying spring-batch test code.

I use StepScopeTestExecutionListener to autowire beans which scoped by step.

(of course, I use this listener as to TestExecutionListeners annotation.)

---

Following bean is injected bean well.

```
<bean id="itemReader" scope="step" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
...
</bean>
```

♪

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier(value="itemReader")
ItemReader<Item> reader;
```

But following is not. That occurs NoSuchBeanDefinitionException with message "No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader] found for dependency"

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier(value="itemReader")
FlatFileItemReader<Item> reader;
```

---

Clearly, I think this is problem about step scope.

But, I don't understand difference between ItemReader and FlatFileItemReader.

Or, Is there a problem in StepScopeTestExecutionListener?

I should test FlatFileItemReader with implemented methods such setResources() or open()... you know what I mean.

please help.

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the fact that XML configuration uses java proxies for step scoped dependencies.  Because of that, the resulting bean definition is only aware of the interface (in this case `ItemReader`).  In order for this to work, you need to either switch to java config completely (currently java config uses dynamic subclassing instead of java proxies) or configure your step scope so that the `proxyTargetClass` is set to true (this uses dynamic subclassing) so that the implementing class information is available.

Comment: very appreciate your comment. I modified some content in question. I forgot adding 'scope="step"' in example itemReader bean, and added. Did you consider that case?

Comment: My answer is still the same.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Following worked for me

```
@Resource(name="itemReader")
ResourceAwareItemReaderItemStream<Item> itemReader
```

or

```
 @Autowired
 @Qualifier("itemReader")
 ResourceAwareItemReaderItemStream<Item> itemReader
```

Complete snap shot

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners( { DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
                           StepScopeTestExecutionListener.class })
@ContextConfiguration({"classpath:spring/jdbc/unit-test-context.xml"})
public class SomeTest  {

        @Resource(name="itemReader")
        ResourceAwareItemReaderItemStream<Item> itemReader
```

Comment: Short remark: The `StepScopeTestExecutionListener` is only available in the separate `spring-batch-test` project.